# filling array of pointers from file in c

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers

I want to read data which is written in `fprintf(fp,"%s %s  %s\n", p->name,p->surname,p->tc);`    format. I created struct patients **p in  with

```
struct patients **create_array(struct patients **ptr,int length){
int i;

    ptr=(struct patients **)malloc(length*sizeof(struct patients));

return ptr;

}
```

function above create array of pointers and give it to main. Main calls read_file() function to read data from file which is written in known format. But my data is not filled when i try to print them in main it prints meaningless things. I thought problem in reading data that's why i put only reading function. What is my problem? All suggestons are welcome.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

struct patients
{
    int importance;
    char name[10], surname[10], tc[11];
};

FILE *file_opening(char x[])
{
    return (fopen(x,"w+"));
}

writing_file (FILE *fp, struct patients *p)
{
    fprintf(fp,"%s %s  %s\n", p->name,p->surname,p->tc);
}

struct patients **read_file (FILE *fp,struct patients **p)
{
    int i=-1;
    do{
    i++;
    }while(fscanf(fp,"%s %s  %s",p[i]->name,p[i]->surname,p[i]->tc) !=EOF);

    return p;
}

void show_all_patients(struct patients **p, int start_index, int length){
int i;

    for(i=start_index;i<length;i++)
        printf("%s %s %s",p[i]->name,p[i]->surname,p[i]->tc);

}

struct patients **create_array(int length){

    return (struct patients **)malloc(length*sizeof(struct patients));

}


int menu(void){
    int choice;
    printf("1)take patient\n2)show all patients\n3)exit");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    return choice;
}

main(){
int i=0,j,choice,cured_patient=0,length=1;
FILE *fp;
struct patients **ptr;
char file_name[40]="patient_list.txt";

ptr=create_array(length);
fp=file_opening(file_name);
ptr=read_file(fp,ptr);


    do{
        choice=menu();

            if(choice==1){
            printf("%s %s %s\n",ptr[i]->name,ptr[i]->surname,ptr[i]->tc);
            i++;
            }
            else if(choice==2){
                show_all_patients(ptr,i,length);
            }
    }while(choice!=3);

for(j=i;j<length;j++)
writing_file(fp,ptr[j]);

fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Does your compiler not give you any useful error messages?

Comment: no. The program is compiled and runs well. Only, problem happens when i try to print values in struct which is in **p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems with the code:

1. There is no return value of `writing_file`. Add `void` as the return type.

   ```
   void writing_file (FILE *fp, struct patients *p)
   {
      fprintf(fp,"%s %s  %s\n", p->name,p->surname,p->tc);
   }
   ```
2. You need `#include <stdlib.h>`.

   Without that the return value of `malloc` is assumed to be an `int`, which can result in strange problems.
3. Syntax errors:

   Given your definition of `ptr`, the lines

   ```
   ptr=create_array(length);
   ```

   and

   ```
   ptr=read_file(fp,ptr);
   ```

   are syntactically invalid. I get the following errors with gcc:

   ```
   soc.c: In function ‘main’:
   soc.c:58:7: error: assignment to expression with array type
       ptr=create_array(length);
          ^
   soc.c:60:7: error: assignment to expression with array type
       ptr=read_file(fp,ptr);
   ```

   If your compiler does not report errors on those two lines, it's time to use a different compiler.
4. Reading and writing to the same file

   You are using the same `FILE*` to read from and write to. It's not clear whether you meant to do that or it was an error on your part.

   When you open the file using:

   ```
   return (fopen(x,"w+"));
   ```

   the contents of the file are truncated. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen for more info. Pay special attention to the table under **Parameters**. It says:

   > "w+"  | write extended    | Create a file for read/write  | destroy contents  | create new

   If you want to just read the data from the file, use

   ```
   return (fopen(x,"r"));
   ```

   If you want to read the data from the file and write back the data to it, read it first using the above mode, close the file, then reopen it using:

   ```
   return (fopen(x,"w"));
   ```
5. Handling the array of patients

   I think you should use:

   ```
   FILE* fp = NULL;
   int length=10;
   struct patients *ptr = NULL;

   ptr=create_array(length);
   fp=file_opening(file_name);
   read_file(fp, ptr, length);
   ```

   Adjust the rest of your code appropriately.
6. Add code to deallocate memory

   Every call to `malloc` should have a corresponding call to `free`. I would add

   ```
   void delete_array(struct patients *ptr)
   {
      free(ptr);
   }
   ```

   and call it from `main` before the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Things that I would change.

1. Return value and input arguments of `create_array`.

   The function can also be simplified to:

   ```
   struct patients* create_array(int length)
   {
      return malloc(length*sizeof(struct patients));
   }
   ```
2. Return value and arguments to `read_file`

   ```
   struct patients* read_file (FILE *fp ,struct patients *p)
   {
       int i=-1;
       do
       {
         i++;
       } while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s  %s",p[i].name, p[i].surname, p[i].tc) != EOF);

       return p;
   }
   ```
3. Make sure that you provide the maximum number of characters to be read. Otherwise, you might end up reading more than the array are capable of holding.

   Change

   ```
       } while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s  %s",p[i].name, p[i].surname, p[i].tc) != EOF);
   ```

   to (given the size of the arrays in your `struct`)

   ```
       } while(fscanf(fp, "%9s %9s %10s",p[i].name, p[i].surname, p[i].tc) != EOF);
   ```

Comment: it must be array of pointers format like `int *p[10];`you make them only pointer which are not connected each other.

Comment: @BeyzaSelvi, is each pointer expected to point to one `struct` or an array of `struct`s?

Comment: p is an array that contains struct patients pointers and each pointer in that array points to one struct. But p is an array of pointers, it's elements holds structs. So p must be `**p` isn't it? Also,  for 3) it doesn't need to ensure that i provide maximum number of characters. fscanf deosnt read spaces and my input/output format is like `"%s %s  %s"`. I wrote the file with that format and if i try to read them in same format it should read it. I gave it less number of maximum or not, it should read until to read a space. so string string  string it must be and it is in that format.

Comment: When a pointer points only one item, it makes sense to use an object instead. If `p` is an array of pointers like you say, my suggestions for `create_array` and `read_array` are not right. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can see where things could be wrong. Regarding use of `%s` vs `%9s`, if a name has more than 9 characters, you will end up using memory that you are not supposed to.  Use of `%9s` will still stop at the next whitespace but it will stop reading after th 9-th character even if the next character is not a whitespace.

Comment: I edited the post as you suggested. Now you can see all of that you want. I supposed that user don't enter bigger string than my limits. How can i read file correctly now?

Comment: @BeyzaSelvi, I'm going to start a new answer.  If I revamp this answer, these comments won't make any sense. I'm going to leave this answer just for these comments.